# MySQL Query - search for person who has all B

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I am trying to solve an SQL question about below question in MySQL

> output the patient name who has taken treatment from all doctors at least once.

I am stuck with the "all doctors".

Is there a way to get this result with one query?

Where I have the table,

```
CREATE table patient (
    pno VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE table doctor (
    dno VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE table record (
    id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    dno VARCHAR(5),
    pno VARCHAR(5),
    
    FOREIGN KEY(dno) REFERENCES doctor(dno)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(pno) REFERENCES patient(pno)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

pno is the patient number, which is referenced by record,
dno is the doctor's number, which is referenced by record.

I think IN and EXSISTS doen't work in this situation.
Maybe using count(*) would work but, I tried using subquery below, and couldn't solve this.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM doctor;
```

Comment: Please use joins to show doctors from all the tables

Comment: This type of query is called [tag:relational-division]. You might like to click that tag here on Stack Overflow to see a variety of solutions.

Comment: @UtsavUpadhyay, Sorry. What do you mean use joins to show doctors from all the tables?

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you. By the definition you have presented, I could grasp the concept of it.

Comment: @mchun please check this to know more about [Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) in SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- first select the cardinality of the doctors,
- then select all patients whose distinct count of doctors is equal to the cardinality of doctors
- hence get the patients' names.

The query should look like this:

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM patient p 
WHERE p.pno IN (
    SELECT r.pno
    FROM record r
    GROUP BY r.pno 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.dno) = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM doctors
    )
)
```

Note: I'll leave an SQL fiddle link here in case of question update with some sample data.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to grasp the concept of division and the use of it. I will keep in mind.